# get PUT and other methods with symfony

Tags: php, rest, symfony, methods, put

i am creating a framework, for studying and improving my skills.
im using symfony components, http foundation and http kernel.
now i want to create a route package for my framework, and i have a problem.
get and post i can get with

```
$request->get('name');
```

i also can choose with 'request' and 'query';

```
$request->request->get('name'); //for POST
$request->query->get('name'); //for GET
```

but i cant hanlde PUT or DELETE or HEAD.
i try to define forms like method are POST and add `<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='PUT'>` but its not helping and it shows as POST
what can i do ?

Comment: Whatever method you use, you can get querystring parameters with `$request->get('name')` or `$request->query->get('name')`. What's that got to do with routing?

Comment: in laravel, for example, you could do `Route::put`. i know i could use "get" method, but it wouldnt seperated between put , post or get. thats my problem.